# Can I have two PAF environments in the PC ( one local system )?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am trying to download two PAF in my local system. How can I have two PAF environments in the PC?
Please resolve this issue with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** Change the environment variable PAF Home, And install the new version.
Then you can have two PAF in the local system.